# Don't understand what's happening when I use parseFloat

Tags: javascript

So basically I have a system that shows you frequently bought together items. However, I need to display the value for the whole bundle, basically item 1 + item 2 + item 3.
So, what I'm trying to do is take the span where the price is appended to, use `$.text()` method on it then sum all the numbers, however, I can't seem to get them, when I use `parseFloat()` it returns `NaN`
my `getPrice` function looks like :

```
function getPrice(discount) {   
        var total_price = 0;
        var active_products = 0;
        $('.bundle-product-checkbox').each(function() {
            if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
                var price = parseFloat($('.bundle-fbt-price > .money').text());
                total_price += price;
                active_products++;
                console.log(total_price);                       
            }
    });

if (active_products == $('.bundle-product-checkbox').length) {
    var savings = (discount / 100) * total_price;
    var discountedPrice = total_price - (discount / 100) * total_price;
    $('.full-bundle-price').text(total_price + ' $').css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    $('.discounted-bundle-price').text(discountedPrice + ' $');
    $('.bundle-savings').text('You save ' + savings + ' $');
} else if (active_products == 0) {
    $('.bundle-add').fadeOut('fast');
} else {
    $('.full-bundle-price').text('Total Price: ' + total_price + ' $');
    $('.full-bundle-price').css("text-decoration", "none");
    $('.discounted-bundle-price').text('');
    $('.bundle-savings').text('');
}
```

My html for this part is

```
{foreach from=$products item=p key=k}
<div style="display:inline-block;float:left;width:100%;">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="bundle-product-checkbox" name="bundle-product-list" data-toggle="{$k}" />
    <span class="bundle-title">{if $k==0 }<b>This Item: {/if}{$p.title} {if $k==0 }</b>{/if}</span> 
                    {if isset($p.variants)}
                        {if $p.variants_count > 1}
                            <select class="vitals_recommended_select bundle_fbt_select">
                                {foreach $p.variants item=v}
                                    <option value="{$v.id}" class="bundle-fbt-money" data-vitals-price="{if $display_currency_code}{$shop.money_with_currency_format|replace:array('{{amount}}','{{amount_with_comma_separator}}'):$v.price}{else}{$shop.money_format|replace:array('{{amount}}','{{amount_with_comma_separator}}'):$v.price}{/if}" data-vitals-discount="{if $v.discount}-{$v.discount}%{else}0{/if}">{$v.title}</option>
                                {/foreach}
                            </select>
                            <p class="vitals-product-price bundle-fbt-price">{if $display_currency_code}{$shop.money_with_currency_format|replace:array('{{amount}}','{{amount_with_comma_separator}}'):$p.variants[0].price}{else}{$shop.money_format|replace:array('{{amount}}','{{amount_with_comma_separator}}'):$p.variants[0].price}{/if} {if $p.variants[0].discount} <span class="vitals-product-discount">-{$p.variants[0].discount}%</span>{/if}</p>
                        {else}
                            <p class="vitals-product-price bundle-fbt-price">{if $display_currency_code}{$shop.money_with_currency_format|replace:array('{{amount}}','{{amount_with_comma_separator}}'):$p.variants[0].price}{else}{$shop.money_format|replace:array('{{amount}}','{{amount_with_comma_separator}}'):$p.variants[0].price}{/if} {if $p.variants[0].discount}<span class="vitals-product-discount">-{$p.variants[0].discount}%</span>{/if}</p>
                        {/if}
                    {/if}
</div>
{/foreach}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show your HTML as well.

Comment: can you show the log of $('.bundle-fbt-price > .money').text()

Comment: I assume `$('.bundle-fbt-price > .money').text()` doesn't only contain numeric values but maybe a currency symbol too or possibly actual words? - Do `console.log($('.bundle-fbt-price > .money').text())` to see what you are trying to process.

Comment: @UllasHunka
the log is
VM598:1 $91.00 USD$45.00 USD$229.00 USD

Comment: @CristiDuma How are you expecting to parse all this as a float?

Comment: @chŝdk well,what should I do in this case?

Comment: @CristiDuma You need to take only numeric values from the input string. I am posting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Don't understand what's happening when I use parseFloat ?

Well all it's happening is that the values you are trying to parse aren't parsebale, because they start with and contain alphabetic characters, so they can't be parsed and will return `NaN`.

If the value you are trying to parse is like this:

```
VM598:1 $91.00 USD$45.00 USD$229.00 USD
```

You need to process it so you can parse it, you can use `split` and `regexp` to extract alll the values from it.

This is what you can do:

```js
var content = "VM598:1 $91.00 USD$45.00 USD$229.00 USD";

var values = content.split(":")[1].split(/\$|USD/).filter((v, i) => {
  return v !== "" && i > 0;
}).map(v => v.trim());
console.log(values);

var amounts = values.map(x => parseFloat(x));
console.log(amounts);
```

Comment: Thanks sir. Nice answer